# HTML5 Computer Parsable Specification

Tags: html, dtd, specifications

Is there a HTML5 specification that can be parsed by computers easily, like the old document type definition files?

Comment: @CBroe That questions asks where it is, I don't. I ask where is the alternative.

Comment: @JeroenBollen: What do you mean by "alternative"?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I am looking for a specification that I can parse and use to parse actual HTML5 and check if it's valid.